# Retrieving Specific Characters with Specific Items in Database on Apache AGE

Tags: postgresql, apache-age, opencypher

I'm currently working with a database that represents an RPG game. It contains nodes for **characters**, **items**, and **locations**. The relationships between these nodes are represented as '**HAS_ITEM**' (between **characters** and **items**) and '**VISITED**' (between **characters** and **locations**).

Items are categorized by a 'Rarity' property which is a value between 1 (common) and 5 (legendary). Similarly, locations are quantified by a 'Visit_Count' property, indicating how often they've been visited by any character.

Here's an excerpt of the database:

```
**Characters.csv:**

Character_Id,Name
1,John
2,Mary
3,Bob
4,Alice

**Items.csv**:

Item_Id,Name,Rarity
1,Sword of Valor,5
2,Shield of Hope,4
3,Wand of Sorcery,3
4,Bow of Speed,4
5,Dagger of Stealth,2

**Locations.csv**

Location_Id,Name,Visit_Count
1,Desert of Sands,15
2,Forest of Mysteries,8
3,Castle of Shadows,25
4,Mountain of Trials,10
5,Sea of Silence,5

**HAS_ITEM.csv**

Character_Id,Item_Id
1,1
2,4
3,2
3,3
4,2
4,5

**VISITED.csv**

Character_Id,Location_Id
1,1
1,2
2,3
2,4
2,5
3,1
3,2
3,3
3,4
4,1
```

Here's where I need some help:

1. I want to filter and retrieve **all characters** who have a 'HAS_ITEM' relationship with **any** item of rarity **4 or above**. These characters should also have a 'VISITED' relationship with **at least 3 different locations**. For each of these characters, I want to display their **name**, the **name(s) of the rare item(s) they own**, and the total **count of unique locations** they've visited.
2. The results should be **sorted** by the **total number of locations visited** in descending order. If multiple characters have visited the same number of locations, then they should be further sorted by their name in ascending alphabetical order.

I tried this:

```
MATCH (c:Character)-[:VISITED]->(l:Location)
WITH c, count(DISTINCT l) as visit_count
MATCH (c)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:Item)
WHERE i.Rarity >= 4 AND visit_count >= 3
RETURN c.name, i.name, visit_count
ORDER BY visit_count DESC, c.name ASC
```

but it returns just one item for each character:

```css
c.name   | i.name            | visit_count
-------------------------------------------
Bob      | Shield of Hope    | 4
Mary     | Bow of Speed      | 3
```

I wanted all the items that a character has that matched the criteria.

Can anyone help me construct a Cypher query for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group the names of items for each character using a function like `collect()`. So, to retrieve all the items that a character has, you can modify the query as follows:

```
MATCH (c:Character)-[:VISITED]->(l:Location)
WITH c, count(DISTINCT l) as visit_count
MATCH (c)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:Item)
WHERE i.Rarity >= 4 AND visit_count >= 3
RETURN c.name, collect(i.name) as items, visit_count
ORDER BY visit_count DESC, c.name ASC
```

By doing so, the query will return all the items a character has rather than just one item.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your question says: the output is a single item matched and I  want the other things>>> If so then I believe you refer to the COLLECT function to aggregate the result into a single row.

```
MATCH (c:Character)-[:VISITED]->(l:Location)
WITH c, count(DISTINCT l) as visit_count
MATCH (c)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:Item)
WHERE i.Rarity >= 4
WITH c, visit_count, COLLECT(i.name) as rare_items
WHERE visit_count >= 3
RETURN c.name, rare_items, visit_count
ORDER BY visit_count DESC, c.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of cyber queries, aggregation functions and pattern matching can be used to achieve the result that you desire. Here's one way to solve this problem:

```
MATCH (c:Character)-[:VISITED]->(l:Location)
WITH c, count(DISTINCT l) as visit_count
WHERE visit_count >= 3
MATCH (c)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:Item)
WHERE i.Rarity >= 4
WITH c, visit_count, i
ORDER BY c.Name ASC, i.Name ASC
RETURN c.Name, COLLECT(DISTINCT i.Name) as RareItems, visit_count
ORDER BY visit_count DESC, c.Name ASC
```